# Golang assignment safety with single reader and single writer

Tags: go, concurrency, atomic

Say I have two go routines:

```
var sequence int64

// writer
for i := sequence; i < max; i++ {
  doSomethingWithSequence(i)
  sequence = i
}

// reader
for {
  doSomeOtherThingWithSequence(sequence)
}
```

So can I get by without `atomic`?

Some potential risks I can think of:

1. reorder (for the writer, updating `sequence` happens before `doSomething`) could happen, but I can live with that.
2. `sequence` is not properly aligned in memory so the reader might observe a partially updated `i`. Running on (recent kernel) linux with x86_64,
   can we rule that out?
3. go compiler 'cleverly optimizes' the reader, so the access to `i` never goes to memory but `cached` in a register. Is that possible in go?
4. Anything else?

Comment: Huh, why not atomic? This type of situation is _why it exists_.

Comment: If you have multiple goroutines where at least one writes a value which others read, without explicit synchronization, that is a data race and therefore undefined behavior. Don't try to find logic in what will happen, it's **undefined**. Use proper synchronization. See [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem).

Comment: You can by "without atomic", but not without **some** synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Go's motto: [Do not communicate by sharing memory; instead, share memory by communicating](https://blog.golang.org/share-memory-by-communicating). Which is an effective best-practice most of the time.

1. If you care about ordering, you care about synchronizing the two goroutines.
2. I don't think they are possible. Anyway, those are not things you should worry about if you properly design the synchronization.
3. The same as above.

Luckily, Go has a [data race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html) integrated. Try to run your example with `go run -race`. You will probably see the race condition happening on `sequence` variable.

Comment: yeah about share memory by communicating, there's also https://blog.acolyer.org/2019/05/17/understanding-real-world-concurrency-bugs-in-go/. Anyway that's not my point. About `go run -race`, it did report data race, but not detailed enough for me.